# Managing build flags in Android

Tags: android, build, release, manifest, flags

I have several options - both in code and in the manifest file - that I would like to easily toggle on and off based on whether it's a debug build or release build.

What's the best way to handle things like this in an Android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use properties files, e.g. one for prod and one for dev. Then you could create an Ant script with two targets, a prod build and a dev build, where the appropriate properties file is copied prior to the APK being built. Make sure that the properties files are copied using the same name, then you can access the deployed one, irrespective of the environment you built for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Tyler mentioned, if you are looking at including optional code in case it is a Debug and not having that code if its a release, then you could look at using the BuildConfig file that is generated by the ADT.

As per the docs: " Added a feature that allows you to run some code only in debug mode. Builds now generate a class called BuildConfig containing a DEBUG constant that is automatically set according to your build type. You can check the (BuildConfig.DEBUG) constant in your code to run debug-only functions such as outputting debug logs."

You will find this file in the Project/gen folder, the same place where the R.java is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Now with Android Studio and Gradle it is easy to do this using the auto generated flag `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. Like:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // Debug code
} else {
    // Resease code
}
```